# In MYSQL, would it be more efficient to run multiple AND checks or casting to Date and using IN to check for multiple date appearances?

Tags: mysql, sql

## What I need to do

I need to be able to check my MYSQL database to see whether or not a record has a start `datetime` that occurs on a selected list of dates. There can be gaps in date ranges, so I can't just use a simple `field >= '12-12-2000 00:00:00 AND field < 12-20-2000 00:00:00`.

I have two solutions in my head, but I don't have enough actual data to actually test whether or not it would be more efficient to use an IN statement, or concatenating a bunch of AND statements to do the checks.

Currently, my thought process leads me to two options.

**using IN**

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE
    CAST(datefield as Date) IN ('12-12-2000', '12-13-2000', '12-15-2000', '12-20-2000');
```

**Using concatenated AND statements**

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE
    (datefield >= '12-12-2000 00:00:00' AND datefield < '12-13-2000 00:00:00')
OR
    (datefield >= '12-13-2000 00:00:00' AND datefield < '12-14-2000 00:00:00')
OR
    (datefield >= '12-15-2000 00:00:00' AND datefield < '12-16-2000 00:00:00')
OR
    (datefield >= '12-20-2000 00:00:00' AND datefield < '12-21-2000 00:00:00')
```

These are two options that I've come up with, however I'm sure there are more experienced SQL Developers out there that have better ways of doing what I'm trying to do. I did read that casting is slower than just ANDing a start and end datetime, however I'm not sure if this would still apply even when I could potentially have 5-30 dates to check per query.

Comment: Step 1: store dates/datetimes as dates/datetimes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CAST` method can't take advantage of an index on the `datefield` column.

MySQL often won't use indexes when you have an `OR` condition, so it may be necessary to change the second version into a `UNION`

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE (datefield >= '12-12-2000 00:00:00' AND datefield < '12-13-2000 00:00:00')
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE (datefield >= '12-13-2000 00:00:00' AND datefield < '12-14-2000 00:00:00')
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE (datefield >= '12-15-2000 00:00:00' AND datefield < '12-16-2000 00:00:00')
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE (datefield >= '12-20-2000 00:00:00' AND datefield < '12-21-2000 00:00:00')
```

BTW, your date formats are wrong, they should be `YYYY-MM-DD`, not `MM-DD-YYYY`.

If you're using MySQL 5.7 or higher, there *is* a way to index the `CAST` version. You can create a [generated column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) whose value is `CAST(datefield AS DATE)`, and add an index on this column.